# taking too long time to sync Ethereum Full Node

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ubuntu, full-node

I'm trying to sync full node for ethereum by using Vultr service.
I borrowed VPS from Vultr service and I try to sync to it but after 3 days, it's still working.
It takes too long time. At first, number of downloading slots are large(100 per seconds) but now 10~20 per seconds. why? network problem or service? or any other problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing a full Ethereum node can be a resource-intensive process, and it's not uncommon for syncing speeds to decrease over time. However, there are a few things you can try to improve the speed:

- Increase the number of target peers: You mentioned that you've already tried this, but it's worth noting that increasing the number of target peers can help improve syncing speed. You can try increasing it further to see if it makes a difference.
- Use a faster VPS: You mentioned that you've already tried with Vultr service, but it's possible that a faster server could help improve syncing speed. However, it's important to note that there may be diminishing returns as you increase the server's resources.
- Use a different syncing client: You mentioned that you're using the Lighthouse client to sync with the Geth client. It's possible that using a different syncing client could help improve syncing speed. For example, you could try using the Parity client instead.
- Use a syncing service: If you're still having trouble syncing your node, you could consider using a syncing service like Infura or QuickNode. These services allow you to connect to their nodes, which are already synced with the Ethereum network and can help you avoid the syncing process altogether.
  It's also worth noting that syncing a full Ethereum node can take a significant amount of time, even with optimal conditions. If you're syncing for the first time, it's not uncommon for the process to take several days or even weeks. However, once your node is synced, subsequent syncs should be faster.